# KeyError accessing field in JSON

Tags: python, json, pagination, python-2.6

Can someone help me access the "pagination" field in the following API response? I have tried the code below but get an error 'pagination'. It works for 'title' so I'm not sure what's different. Full error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 172, in <module>
    pag_object = (data['pagination'])
KeyError: 'pagination'
```

My code:

```
response = requests.get("https://api.weather.gov/alerts?limit=1", timeout=5)
data = response.json()
pag_object = (data['pagination'])
```

I have verified that the JSON is valid. Snippet below.

```
{
    "@context": [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojson/geojson-ld/master/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld",
        {
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"
        }
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "id": "http://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-22613",
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "@type": "wx:Alert",
            "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-22613",
            "areaDesc": "Montgomery",
            "geocode": {
                "UGC": [
                    "MDC031"
                ],
                "SAME": [
                    "024031"
                ]
            },
            "affectedZones": [
                "http://api.weather.gov/zones/county/MDC031"
            ],
            "references": [],
            "sent": "2018-05-21T14:05:51+00:00",
            "event": "Test Message",
            "senderName": "NWS",
            "description": "Monitoring message only. Please disregard.",
            "parameters": {
                "PIL": [
                    "NWSKEPWBC"
                ],
                "BLOCKCHANNEL": [
                    "CMAS",
                    "NWEM"
                ]
            }
        }
    }],
    "title": "Watches, warnings, and advisories",
    "pagination": {
        "next": "http://api.weather.gov/alerts?limit=1&cursor=eyJ0IjoxNTI2OTExNTUxLCJpIjoiTldTLUlEUC1QUk9ELUtFRVBBTElWRS0yMjYxMyJ9"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error. `name 'pagination' not defined` sounds like a `NameError` exception, not a key error, indicating you made a programming error.

Comment: But the response object does indeed not have a `'pagination'` key in the top-level dictionary. The key may exist in a nested dictionary, but you'd have to create an expression that will access the dictionary that does have that key.

Comment: You might have used `pagination` as variable somewhere, its not a key error

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem on my computer. Everything's fine.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov: and I can, because the response returned to my call indeed doesn't have a `pagination` key. Clearly, you can't count on the key being present.

Comment: If there is not always a `'pagination'` key in the top-level object you need to code defensively. Use exception handling or `dict.get()` and then testing if `None` was returned instead, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have edited the description to include the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service doesn't always include a pagination key. If there are no further pages of data, the key is omitted.

Test for it (`if 'pagination' in data:)`, specify a default value (`data.get('pagination', {})`) or use a `try...except KeyError` exception handler to deal with the link missing.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The response is in fact missing the key.